# How to detect the end of the loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)` I can easily detect if the loop is at the end.

But I how can I know if I'm using for or for each.

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if(End of for) //Do something if the end of the loop

}
```

how to find the last loop in for in javascript ?

Comment: How about `i===(str.length-1)` ? If you wants to do something after for loop completes then do it after for loop!

Comment: In general, you can't.

Comment: if the for loop has ended, then how can you add code within the for loop to handle that case? did you consider adding 'something if end of loop code'  right after for loop?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? You state initially that you can "easily detect" the end of one loop, then ask how to detect the end of the same loop. Your last statement also suggests you may be trying to ask about [`for..in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {        
    if(i== str.length-1) { 
    //Do something if the end of the loop    
    }
}
```

using forin

```
 for (var item in str) {
      if(str[str.length-1] == item) {
        //Do something if the end of the loop
      }
    }
```

Comment: This will not notify end of loop, it will specify last iteration in the loop! Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @RayonDabre "Last iteration" may be what the OP means by the "end of the loop." The question isn't overly clear either way.

Comment: This is clearly run while the last loop is in progress. If put at the end of loop block then is as last code in the loop. But it's not called AFTER the loop. Author phrased question so poorly it's hard to determine what the question is :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const str = "I am a 24 letter string!";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

  if (i + 1 === str.length) {
    console.log('Last loop:', i + 1)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var item in str) {
    if(str[parseInt(item)+1] === undefined) {
        //Do something if the end of the loop
    }
}



 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

     if(i == (arr.length - 1)){
      //do you stuff
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the last thing from the loop. Note the use of `str.length - 1` in the condition.

```
//from the beginning up to but not including the last index
for(var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(i)
}
//from the last index only
console.log(str.length - 1)
```

In a `forEach` loop, you must iterate linearly over the array, so some conditional logic and a counter are necessary to detect the last element. I find the below harder to read and less efficient especially if you really use an anonymous function in that way. Moreover because of this need for a counter, it simply makes more sense to use the first approach I shared.

```
var i = 0;
array.forEach(function(i) {
    if(i === str.length - 1) {
        //do the last thing
    } else {
        //do all the other things
    }
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use console.log(). If you put this inside the loop, you will be able to view each result in the console.

```
console.log(i);
```